# In the Erdős–Rényi model, calculate the probability that the graph is bipartite

Tags: probability, graph-theory, random-graphs

I have an issue with a question below.

**In the Erdős–Rényi model on 4 vertices with p=0.5, calculate the probability that the graph is bipartite.**

As far as I know we have 4^3 = 64 possible graphs. But how to calculate probability that graph is bipartite.

Thank you, in advance.

Comment: With $p = 0.5$, all $64$ graphs (which I feel like it's more intuitive to get via $2^6$ than $4^3$, but you do you) are equally likely. How many are bipartite?

Comment: 2^6 because
we have to pick 2 out of 4 to get connected vertex?
so it is like 4!/(2!2!) = 6

and then we have 2^6 combinations?

Comment: Yes, I dunno How to calculate bipartite graphs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With only $4$ vertices, the number of possibilities is limited, so there's many ways to count all the bipartite graphs. Then, divide by $2^6 = 64$ to get the probability. (Here, $6 = \binom 42$ is the total number of possible edges: the number of edges in the complete graph $K_4$.)

It is useful to remember that a graph is bipartite if and only if it has no odd cycles. With $4$ vertices, the only possible odd cycle is $C_3$.

- If you have $0$, $1$, or $2$ edges, there cannot be any odd cycles, so there are $\binom 60 + \binom 61 + \binom 62$ cases here.
- If you have $3$ edges, not all $\binom 63$ cases work; the graph might be $C_3$ plus an isolated vertex. How many cases must we rule out?
- If you have $4$ edges, only a few cases work: the only bipartite graph on $4$ vertices and $4$ edges up to isomorphism is $K_{2,2} = C_4$. How many ways are there to get $C_4$?
- With $5$ and $6$ edges, there are no bipartite graphs to speak of.

---

Another reasonable approach is to use the inclusion-exclusion principle on the four possible $3$-cycles that could appear in the graph, to find the probability that none of them appear.

Comment: okey, for the first case we have 1 +6 +15 = 22 cases
For the second? 20 - 4 = 16 cases. Am I right?
for third case we have = 4

22+16+4 = 42 bipartite graphs?

Comment: Thank you so much! for the detailed explanation

Comment: Your count of the $4$-edge case is off by $1$.

Comment: Thank you, it was so helpful.